# INTERNAL ERROR: Trying to add control point not belonging to the segment - Road Traffic Library - Anylogic

Tags: java, anylogic

When I run a Road Proyect in AnyLogic, some seconds after starts simulation is given this error:

[image: Error]

Console:

[image: Console]

I only have the car simple car logic and road elements.

Comment: could you show your model and what you have done?

Comment: Here is the ALP file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JknAi4LUaCoCG3bDw3fZsb70rnArhtO6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It is a Highway with somo in and out points with the logic. Number of cars for each in point are all 1000.

Comment: I meant "please present your model and the problem and what you have already tried to fix it", following https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask recommendations. Most folk here are happy to help but do not have much time to open a model and dig into the depth of the problem. So make life easy for us to help you :-) (but sharing the alp as part of that is great as well)

Comment: Ok, the objective of the project is simulate a highway. For this I have been "drawing" the roads, then I created the logic part (Tipical "car source, move to x road"). So with this "simple" disposition it should at least run during one hour (free edition it restricted to one hour), however when I run the project it starts doing well, but suddenly happens this error. I have been looking for some documentation since days about why it happen, but I didn't found anything.
Into the logic part, I tryed with the smaller funtional (Go A to B) but the error its the same.
Many thanks

Comment: This is a very big and complex model. Best advice: Strip it back until the error disappears so you can find out what is causing it. Impossible to say this way. One small supicion: Sometimes, cars are created to close to an intersection, not having enough time to switch to their expected lane. Make sure this does not happen... Apart from that: simply :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of the error (but not the reason).

There are many times when a road has a pronunciated angle, that sometimes cars throw the "control point error".
[image: error]

So, when you detect the part of the road that gives the error, right-click and round the part of the road.
[image: solution]

---

This should solve the problem, but it's normal that be in a lot of places, so this is a very slow debug work.

Thanks to Benjamin for the advice!